# Universal elimination when $\forall$ is not the main operator

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

I was asked to apply universal elimination on $\forall x A(x) \rightarrow B,$ but the $\forall$ here is not the main operator, what should I do?
here's the question and what I have for now
[image]

Comment: You cannot.....

Comment: I am trying to prove $\forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \vdash \exists x (A(x) \rightarrow B)$, I will edit the question and post what I have for now

Answer (score 1):

> Universal elimination when $∀$ is not the main operator.

You cannot apply UE when the quantifier is not the main operator.

You have to derive $\forall x A(x)$ in order to use it to "detach" $B$ using ($\to$-E):

1. $\forall x A(x) \to B$ --- premise
2. $\lnot \exists x (A(x) \to B)$ --- assumed [a]
3. $\lnot A(y)$ --- assumed [b]
4. $A(y)$ --- assumed [c]
5. $\bot$
6. $B$ --- from 5)
7. $A(y) \to B$ --- from 4) and 6) by ($\to$-I), discharging [c]
8. $\exists x (A(x) \to B)$ --- from 7) by ($\exists$-I)
9. $\bot$
10. $\lnot \lnot A(y)$ --- from 3) and 9) by ($\to$-I), discharging [b]
11. $A(y)$ --- from 10) by ($\lnot \lnot$-E)
12. $\forall x A(x)$ --- from 11) by ($\forall$-I)
13. $B$ --- from 1) and 12) by ($\to$-E)
14. $A(y) \to B$ --- from 13) by ($\to$-I)
15. $\exists x (A(x) \to B)$ --- from 14) by ($\exists$-I)
16. $\bot$

> 17. $\exists x (A(x) \to B)$ --- from 2) and 16) by ($\to$-I), discharging [a], followed by ($\lnot \lnot$-E)

Comment: line 14 won't work because $\rightarrow I$ rule needs to start with an assumption, I'll update what I have

Comment: @n.yc - it works. It is enough to reiterate the assumption...

Comment: Well it doesn't work as I posted...Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @n.y - 10 is not an assumption. After 12 assume $A(a)$ and then re-iterate $B$.

Comment: But in this case the $A(a)\rightarrow B$ will be the second layer, but the final conclusion will need to be at the out most layer?